# Как вывести все строки в MySql

Tags: php, mysql

ДД,
Вывожу товар, по артиклу,
дуелаю запрос в бд на пхп,
вывожу:

```
$request = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM `tbl_product` WHERE `vendor_code` LIKE \''.$_GET['words'].'\''));
echo $request['article'];
```

В данном случае все выводится;
Но что делать если имеются несколько строк под одним и тем же article, ответ придёт как массив? и как его вывести. Можете привести маленький пример. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: фетчить в цикле пока фетчится

Comment: @teran можете привести пример?

Comment: [открываете документацию и смотрите пример №2](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score -1):

Разберитесь в коде что я присалал. Подставьте свои данные. Вам нужно использовать while луп.

```
<?php 

$db = new mysqli('localhost','admin','studentpass', 'mysqli');

$users = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");

while ($row = $users->fetch_array()) {
echo $row->first_name, '<br>';
}


?>
```

И еще кусок кода на.

```
    <?php 



$host='localhost';
$dbuser='admin';
$pass='studentpass';
$dbname='student';
$conn=mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser,$pass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('Connection Failed!' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Querying the Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 


$sql = 'SELECT * FROM student_info';
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (!$res) {
    die('Query Failed!');
}

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        echo $key .": " . $val."<br>";
    }
    echo "<br><hr><br>";
}
mysqli_free_result($res);

 ?>


</body>
</html>

 <?php mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```